# How can I obtain every directory name of my path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory

How can I get the name of every directory of my current path?

I got my absolute path with the following code :

```
var completeDir = __dirname;
```

This returns me something like that :

> C:\Users\Administrator\AA\BB\CC\DD

I would like to able to get AA, BB, CC, DD.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to just pop path in here, which makes it cleaner?

```
var path = require('path');
var dirs = __dirname.split(path.sep).reverse( );
```

Answer (score 1):

pharaon450's answer is correct, but you may want you script to be more portable and also account for slashes as Unix path separators, in case your script is run there:

```
dirArray = __dirname.split(/[\\|\/]/)).reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

I split my path into an array with the following code

```
var completeDirName = __dirname;
var dirArray = completeDirName.split('\\').reverse();
```